# Spacing around lstquestion when solution are not printed

Tags: spacing, listings, exsheets

The [`exsheets`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exsheets) gives handy commands to write exams, with a nice switch to print the answers. It also provides an environment to print code (using the `exsheets-listings` package).

However, even when the solutions are not printed, the spacing between two questions, when the solution is given in a `lstsolution` environment, is inconsistent.

Mwe :

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{exsheets-listings}

%\SetupExSheets{solution/print=true}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
Write a statement that assign the value $10$ to the variable \texttt{x}.
\end{question}

\begin{lstsolution}
x = 10;
\end{lstsolution}

\begin{question}
Here comes another question.
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
A solution that is not made of code.
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
And a last question to see the spacing.
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

A `lstsolution`, which is not printed, is between Exercise 1 and Exercise 2, and the space between those two Exercises is greater than the space between Exercise 2 and Exercise 3.

Is that a feature? Is there any neat workaround (with just fitting the spaces "by hand")?

[image]

Comment: the problem appears to be in the definition of the `lstsolution` environment.  this should be reported to the package maintainer as a bug.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I tracked it down, see my answer. I'm not sure it counts as a bug

Comment: @clemens -- to my surprise, very shortly after making this comment, the ctan-ann notice of an updated `exsheets` arrived in my mailbox.  it's great to have an observant maintainer on the line here (no matter what the real cause of the problem).

Comment: @clemens Yes, thanks for patching your package (which was not the cause of the problem, obviously) so quickly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a feature of `exsheets` but of `listings` – the following is was happens behind the scenes of `exheets-listings` causing the behaviour:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{codetest}{}{}

\begin{document}

some text

some text

\begin{codetest}
\end{codetest}

some text

\end{document}
```

[image]

The vertical space is a combination of listings `aboveskip` and `belowskip` parameters. You can set both parameters to zero if the solution is not printed:

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{lstsolution}
  {\PrintSolutionsF{\lstset{aboveskip=0pt,belowskip=0pt}}}
```

Applied to your example:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{exsheets-listings}

\AtBeginEnvironment{lstsolution}
  {\PrintSolutionsF{\lstset{aboveskip=0pt,belowskip=0pt}}}


\begin{document}

\begin{question}
Write a statement that assign the value $10$ to the variable \texttt{x}.
\end{question}

\begin{lstsolution}
x = 10;
\end{lstsolution}

\begin{question}
Here comes another question.
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
A solution that is not made of code.
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
And a last question to see the spacing.
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Do you think I should open another question that address this specific behavior of `listings`, or should I edit my first question?

Comment: @Clément see my edited answer

Comment: I should probably add this to `exsheets-listings`

Comment: (Yes, please, do!) Just a quick, related question: do you think the spacing around `lstquestion` environments is correct? It looks like the code has too much free space around it (especially if the is a pre and a post-text), but it might just be a perspective, or a question related to `listings`, more than to `exsheets`. I can make my question more precise if you want and provide a MWE.